# looking for stand-alone class loader

Tags: java, classloader, packaging, ear

I do have a standalone java program consisting of my own jar and many dependent libraries as single archives (build wby maven, actually 15 JAR files in total). Do some one have already a nice solution she/he can recommend to me how to avoid this and to make packaging smarter?

For example packaging like EAR archives do would be great, but is there any standalone EAR class loader I could use from my NON-Java EE application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's the [Eclipse Fat Jar plugin](http://fjep.sourceforge.net/).  In their own words:

> The Fat Jar Eclipse Plug-In is a Deployment-Tool which deploys an
>   Eclipse java-project into one executable jar.
>
> It adds the Entry "Build Fat-JAR" to the Export-Wizard. In addition to
>   the eclipse standard jar-exporter referenced classes and jars are
>   included to the "Fat-Jar", so the resulting jar contains all needed
>   classes and can be executed directly with "java -jar", no classpath
>   has to be set, no additional jars have to be deployed.
>
> Jars, External-Jars, User-Libraries, System-Libraries, Classes-Folders
>   and Project-Exports are considered by the plugin. The Main-Class can
>   be selected and Manifest-files are merged. The One-JAR option
>   integrates a specialised Class-Loader written by Simon Tuffs (
>   http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/ ) which handles jar-files inside a
>   jar. Individual files and folders can be excluded or added to the jar.
>   Different settings can be stored and re-executed as "Quick Build" via
>   the context-menu.

Comment: This one sounds what I am looking for: "Class-Loader written by Simon Tuffs ( http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/ ) which handles jar-files inside a jar"

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know which IDE you're using. I have Eclipse Indigo (3.7). For me the steps are simple:

1. Right-click on your Java Project folder
2. Click Export
3. On the window that comes up select Java>Runnable JAR file and then click Next
4. On the next window, select the configuration you want your program to run in
5. Select your destination folder
6. On the "Library handling:" part *make sure* you select "Extract required libraries into generated JAR", this will unpack your libraries and then repack them into your finished .jar
7. Click Finish
8. You're done! Enjoy.

If you have an eclipse version less than Ganymede (3.4) you need to get the [Fat Jar Plug-in](http://fjep.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: These steps are basically the same as the Fat Jar plugin. The Fat Jar plugin was integrated into Eclipse Ganymede onwards.

Comment: Using eclipse is not an option, I also do not want to extract the dependency jars as some of them could have internal ressources. What I am looking for is some kind of "outside" container into which I can put my JARs, exactly as I can do it by using EARs.